# Everyone wants me, but I'm easy to find

Tags: riddle, word

> Only a few will find me,
>   But those who do,
>   Put in little effort,
>   Yet the benefits are true.
>
> You're all looking for me,
>   It's funny that way,
>   You think it's impossible to have me,
>   But I'm here every day.
>
> Try as you might, all you do is stress,
>   You'll never get me that way,
>   Just be content with less.
>
> You've caught glimpses before,
>   But it's never enough,
>   For without me, life's pretty tough.
>
> I'm here and waiting for all who are wise,
>   But you need to find yourself first,
>   Before you can win any prize.

***Who am I?***

Comment: I would guess it is something like a state of mind or emotion, but "happiness" does not fit all the clues, especially the last one.

Comment: @Element118, you were correct in your first guess. It fits the last one, because any prize including success / happiness / money can only be achieved through analysis and improvement of yourself (finding yourself)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are talking about

> Inner peace (nirvana)

Only a few will find me,

> Only a few dedicated individuals are able to attain inner peace.

But those who do,
Put in little effort,

> The secret to achieving inner peace is to shed away all worries, and ensure that there is no effort exerted by the mind.

Yet the benefits are true.

> The benefits of inner peace are an enhanced state of living.

You're all looking for me,
It's funny that way,
You think it's impossible to have me,
But I'm here every day.

> Almost everyone wishes to have inner peace but only a few manage to achieve it. It can be achieved anytime, if we just let go of our wordly desires.

Try as you might, all you do is stress,
You'll never get me that way,

> Stressing about inner peace is never going to let you achieve inner peace.

Just be content with less.

> One of the greatest principles of nirvana includes shedding of all materialistic desires.

You've caught glimpses before,
But it's never enough,

> We all find ourselves at peace during certain activities (like a spa or yoga session) but it's not enough for us to remain stress free for good.

For without me, life's pretty tough.

> Life without peace is quite miserable.

I'm here and waiting for all who are wise,
But you need to find yourself first,
Before you can win any prize.

> In order to attain inner peace, you need to accept yourself and only such a wise attitude can lead one to nirvana.

Comment: The original answer was happiness, but for one searching for peace I suppose they are relatively indistinguishable, so will go with this as an answer! Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

myguess is

> inner peace/serenity

Only a few will find me,

But those who do,

Put in little effort,

> very few people find peace and they find it because they work only as much as they require

Yet the benefits are true.

You're all looking for me,

It's funny that way,

> the benefits of peace cant be calculated and everyone is looking for it

You think it's impossible to have me,

But I'm here every day.

Try as you might, all you do is stress,

You'll never get me that way,

> some people think it is impossible to have inner peace.but is always there and if you are stress you obviously cannot get it

You'll never get me that way,

Just be content with less.

You've caught glimpses before,

But it's never enough,

> as the line says you can never get peace if you are stress and you get it only when you are content. sometimes we get it but its not enough

For without me, life's pretty tough.

I'm here and waiting for all who are wise,

But you need to find yourself first,

Before you can win any prize.

> if you dont have peace life can be frustrating. only the wise get it (cause people who do wrong things can never get it). inner peace is to know yourself first. and once you find inner peace you can win any prize

Comment: You are correct, but CodeNewbie got in before you!